# How can we use d3-funnel with React? I tried implementing it but getting some errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, queryselector

```
import React , {useRef , useEffect} from 'react';
import D3Funnel from 'd3-funnel';

function RecruitmentFunnel() {

    useEffect(() => {
        

    var data = [
        ['Applicants', 267 , '#1e4684', '#1e4684'],
        ['Interviews', 134,  '#1e4684'],
        ['Assessments', 48,  '#1e4684'],
        ['Hired',26,  '#1e4684']
    ];

    var options = {
        width : 200,
        height : 400,
        bottomWidth : 1/2,
        bottomPinch : 0,      // How many sections to pinch
        isCurved : true,     // Whether the funnel is curved
        curveHeight : 10,     // The curvature amount
        fillType : "gradient",   // Either "solid" or "gradient"
        isInverted : false,   // Whether the funnel is inverted
        hoverEffects : true,  // Whether the funnel has effects on hover
        fontSize : '18px'
    };

    var funnel = new D3Funnel( data, options );
    funnel.draw ( "#funnel" );
    
    },[])

    return <div id="funnel"></div>;
}

export default RecruitmentFunnel;
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4hDU.png)

Comment: `#funnel` does not yet exist when you call for it.  You will need to use a ref to find it.  Perhaps put your `draw()` function in a `componentDidUpdate()` function, so it can find the div.  And, you should call `render()`

Comment: I am using Functional Component instead of Class 
Yes, adding ref to the div worked
Thanks @GAEfan

Comment: I will format as answer for posterity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#funnel` does not yet exist when you call for it. You will need to use a ref to find it. Example:

```
import { select } from "d3-selection";

constructor(props) {
    this.ref = React.createRef();
}

render() {

    funnel.draw( d3.select(this.ref.current) );

    return <div ref = { this.ref } ></div>;
}
```